Ethernaut reentrancy question
It seems like the SafeMath occurs the error to solve this problem. Does anyone still able to compile this contract?
" Error: not found openzeppelin-contracts-06/math/SafeMath.sol "


It seems like the SafeMath occurs the error to solve this problem

I did a check and the problem can be solved without error from SafeMath.
You can compile the contract on Remix IDE by change import to import "@openzeppelin/contracts@3.3.0/math/SafeMath.sol";
